# How to install UML plugin for Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, uml

I'm programming with Eclipse and I wanna use UML diagrams in **Eclipse Indigo**. I try to install either **UML2** or **UML2 Tools** plugins but I don't succeed.

By the way, I downloaded ZIP files of EMF, XSD, UML2 SDK, UML2 Tools and extracted them then copy their files into plugins and features folders. I see installed files in Eclipse but I can't yet work with it.

I don't know what should I do. Could you tell me, please?

Comment: You have accepted an answer but your last comment on the answer is confusing - delete the comment or explain it !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way to get a version of Eclipse with all the UML plugins is to download the Eclipse Modeling Tools distribution from [this page](http://eclipse.org/downloads/).

Comment: Yeah, I know. I installed Eclipse Modeling Tools but didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

If you only have downloaded the "plain" Eclipse Classic (and not EMT as @ChrisH suggested), go to `Help->Install Modeling Components` and install "Papyrus" that should get you started with UML.

Comment: Thanks ShiDoiSi, I install Papyrus and can draw kinds of diagrams. but I can't generate code.
Could you tell me how can I generate code?

Comment: @omidnazifi After you have the `.uml`-file, run the "EMF Generator Model" wizard and import the UML model. With that, you will be able to generate Java classes from your model.

Answer (score 1):

Insert Eclipse Indigo update site in Install new Software -->Modelling.
There you will see one category named as modelling.Expand it & choose UML & then follow the procedure.

Answer (score 0):

I've installed the Luna version of Eclipse Modeling https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-modeling-tools/lunar and the "EMF Generator Model" wizard is not found under the Eclipse Modeling Framework.  I've reviewed the Luna documentation to see if the generator is embedded or moved to a different package.  I also installed Papyrus and all of the EMF related packages that were not installed and restarted.  No luck yet.

[image]